# Rotation of 3d object with touch in Android using "min3d" framework

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, opengl-es, 3d

I am facing problem for rotating 3d model object. when i load my 3d object in  `GLSerfaceView` with `Scene` Object the rotation is not working properly.

when i touch the screen and move down means top to bottom then it is working fine as i expected. but when i touch the screen from left to right the it is not rotate as i expected.

```
   glSurfaceView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            switch(motionEvent.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    previousX = motionEvent.getX();
                    previousY = motionEvent.getY();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                    x = motionEvent.getX();
                    y = motionEvent.getY();

                    float deltaX = (x - previousX) / density / 2f;
                    float deltaY = (y - previousY) / density / 2f;


                    objModel.rotation().x = objModel.rotation().x + deltaY;
                    objModel.rotation().y = objModel.rotation().y + deltaX;
                    previousX = x;
                    previousY = y;
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Unity3d?

Comment: its not related to Unity3d but i just want some answer from unity3d experts. so that is why i add unity3d tag in question.

Comment: @PrashantJajal Have you tried other `MotionEvent` like `ACTION_SCROLL` to get scroll offsets?

Comment: ok thanks let me try that @boxed__l

Comment: @boxed__l how can i get scroll offsets?

Comment: Just checked the documentation...it seems ACTION_SCROLL is not available for `onTouch` events..it is delegated to  `onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent)` [(Documentation)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_SCROLL)

Comment: okay. thanks for answering

Comment: @PrashantJajal Have you found the solution ?

Comment: @PrashantJajal Have you found any solution?